# How to get different values from 2 object arrays using underscore js

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, underscore.js

How to get different values from 2 object arrays using underscore js.
I have 2 object arrays like this

```
var a = [{
    "asset_id": 1,
    "asset_type": 2
}, {
    "asset_id": 1,
    "asset_type": 3
}, {
    "asset_id": 3,
    "asset_type": 3
}, {
    "asset_id": 5,
    "asset_type": 2
}, {
    "asset_id": 9,
    "asset_type": 3
}, {
    "asset_id": 10,
    "asset_type": 3
}];

var b = [{
    "asset_id": 1,
    "asset_type": 2
}, {
    "asset_id": 1,
    "asset_type": 3
}, {
    "asset_id": 3,
    "asset_type": 3
}];
```

My result should be like this

```
[{
    "asset_id": 5,
    "asset_type": 2
}, {
    "asset_id": 9,
    "asset_type": 3
}, {
    "asset_id": 10,
    "asset_type": 3
}]
```

Is there any inbuilt functions to this in underscorejs

Comment: What are you filtering from your array of `a`s and `b`s to be within your result? Your result looks like it's just picking the last 3 items form array `a`.

Comment: @KristianRoebuck the result is non-common items from 2 object array

Comment: Please provide a proper explanation of the criteria for all to read. People shouldn't have to be diff tools to understand. Also show what you have tried that isn't working

Comment: In your example you have some objects in your results are exist within `a` and `b`. It's probably worth correcting that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve it using [`_.reject`](http://underscorejs.org/#reject) and [`_.findWhere`](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere).

```js
var a = [{
    "asset_id": 1,
    "asset_type": 2
}, {
    "asset_id": 1,
    "asset_type": 3
}, {
    "asset_id": 3,
    "asset_type": 3
}, {
    "asset_id": 5,
    "asset_type": 2
}, {
    "asset_id": 9,
    "asset_type": 3
}, {
    "asset_id": 10,
    "asset_type": 3
}];

var b = [{
    "asset_id": 1,
    "asset_type": 2
}, {
    "asset_id": 1,
    "asset_type": 3
}, {
    "asset_id": 3,
    "asset_type": 3
}];

var newArr = _.reject(a, function(obj) {
  return _.findWhere(b, obj)
})

console.log(newArr)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```